# Subtracting one value from another not working

Tags: liquid

```
{% assign Consumed = 0 %}
{% if Data.Subscription.LatestODO__c > Data.Subscription.PreviousODO__c %}
{% assign Consumed = Data.Subscription.LatestODO__c | minus: Data.Subscription.PreviousODO__c %}
{% endif %}
```

Can anybody tell me why the above Liquid syntax won't produce a result in Consumed?
I check it before the subtraction and it has a value of 0, but it's blank when I check it afterwards.

Where Data.Subscription.LatestODO__c = 107405
and Data.Subscription.PreviousODO__c = 20869

The above syntax works fine where I am dealing with a result that is much smaller than 86536. Any advice for a novice would be appreciated. Than

Comment: Is this in a public repository? I don't see any reason this shouldn't work, but with this little information, it will be impossible to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Your data values might not come in the number format. Please try this code:

```
{% assign Consumed = 0 %}
{% assign LatestODO__c = Data.Subscription.LatestODO__c %}
{% assign PreviousODO__c = Data.Subscription.PreviousODO__c = 20869 %}
{% if Data.LatestODO__c > PreviousODO__c %}
{% assign Consumed = LatestODO__c | minus: PreviousODO__c %}
{% endif %}
```